# JPA Left Join and Count

Tags: hibernate, jpa, count, left-join, named-query

I want to retrieve all **Foo objects** and for every Foo object the **number of associated Bar objects** (zero or more) from the database. I want to do this in **one single query** and I don't want to fetch lists of Bar objects just to get their sizes.

The following works, but obviously only returns Foo objects that have matching Bar objects:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Foo.findAndCountBars", query = "
    SELECT new com.test.MyResultContainer(f, COUNT(b.id))
    FROM Foo f, Bar b
    WHERE f.uniqueKey = b.uniqueKey
    GROUP BY f.id
")
```

Notice that Foo and Bar are not connected via primary keys. The following is what I want to achieve (without an explicit relationship such as `@OneToMany` in `Foo`):

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Foo.findAndCountBars", query = "
    SELECT new com.test.MyResultContainer(f, COUNT(b.id))
    FROM Foo f LEFT JOIN Bar b
    ON f.uniqueKey = b.uniqueKey
    GROUP BY f.id
")
```

I tried different syntax variations, but basically Eclipse tells me that `b.id` is unknown because `Bar` is not in the `FROM` clause. How can I do this?